# find . -type d -mtime +1 only shows one file in a 4 day span

Tags: find, date

I was trying to use `find` with `-mtime +1` to find all directories older than 24 hours but having issues getting this done. I understand that using `-mtime +n` should remove n*24 hours of data but it seems to only find one folder to remove - `2019-07-05`.  Why doesn't it also offer the `2019-07-06` folder?

From `find` man page:

```
-mtime n
File's  data  was  last modified n*24 hours ago.
```

Example:

```
[user@craptaindee mysql] find /some/folder/mysql/ -type d -mtime +1
/some/folder/mysql/2019-07-05

[user@craptaindee mysql] find /some/folder/mysql/ -type d 
/some/folder/mysql/
/some/folder/mysql/2019-07-07
/some/folder/mysql/2019-07-06
/some/folder/mysql/2019-07-08
/some/folder/mysql/2019-07-05
```

Here are the timestamps on the folders

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  5 23:40 2019-07-05
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  6 23:40 2019-07-06
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  7 23:40 2019-07-07
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  8 13:00 2019-07-08
```

I was able to complete my task using `-mmin` but I don't understand why `-mtime` doesn't act as I would expect from the `man` page. Also, `-ctime` doesn't show the other directory either.

EDIT: I completed these tests just before making this post in the early afternoon in the Pacific Timezone at roughly ~13:00 on July 08 2019.

Comment: "roughly ~13:00 on July 08 2019" – So this is an *exact* duplicate of the linked question. In your case files "older than 2 days" are from before ~13:00 on July 06 2019. The file `2019-07-06` doesn't qualify because of its later hour.

Comment: Got it -- then I should use `+0` instead of `+1`. Thanks @Kancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding daystart with find command

```
find /path -type d -daystart -mtime +1
```

Comment: This might have part of the answer im looking for! `man find` shows `-daystart` "Measure times (for -amin, -atime, -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and -mtime) from the  beginning of today  rather  than from 24 hours ago."